# Understanding error when using partial function application or curry in conjunction with overload and std::visit

Tags: c++, functional-programming, overloading, copy-constructor, boost-hana

### tl;dr

I'd like to understand what's wrong with the first code below, i.e. what the error is telling me.

### MRE

I've been able to [shorten the example to the following](https://godbolt.org/z/1fd78bn7E), which generates the same error as the original code below:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp>

auto l1 = [](int){};    using L1 = decltype(l1);
auto l2 = [](double){}; using L2 = decltype(l2);
auto l3 = [](float){};  using L3 = decltype(l3);

using Ovl = boost::hana::overload_t<L1, L2, L3>
//const // uncomment to prevent error
;

Ovl ovl{l1,l2,l3};

Ovl ovl2{ovl}; // this triggers the compilation error
```

### Original question

I'm having trouble understanding the errors I get when I try partially applying `std::visit` to a visitor function obtained via `boost::hana::overload`. (I know that I can't pass around the name of a template function, so I can't really partially apply `std::visit`, so I wrapped it in a generic lambda named just `visit`; I've not bothered doing perfect forwarding because I hardly believe it's relevant to the question.)

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/curry.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>;

int main() {
    std::vector<var_t> vec = {10, 15l, 1.5, "hello"};

    auto visitor = boost::hana::overload([](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
                    [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
                    [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; }
                    );
    auto visit = [](auto const& visitor_, auto const&... visited_){
        return std::visit(visitor_, visited_...);
    };
    for (auto& v: vec) {
        boost::hana::partial(visit, visitor)(v);  // the error is essentially
        boost::hana::curry<2>(visit)(visitor)(v); // the same on these 2 lines
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The error is ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1hGv6rYre)):

```
In file included from deleteme.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr boost::hana::overload_t<F, G>::overload_t(F_&&, G_&& ...) [with F_ = boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&; G_ = {}; F = main()::<lambda(auto:22)>; G = {main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)>}]’:
/usr/include/boost/hana/detail/ebo.hpp:62:36:   required from ‘constexpr _hana::ebo<K, V, true>::ebo(T&&) [with T = boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&; K = boost::hana::detail::bti<1>; V = boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/basic_tuple.hpp:70:65:   required from ‘constexpr boost::hana::detail::basic_tuple_impl<std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, _Idx ...>, Xn ...>::basic_tuple_impl(Yn&& ...) [with Yn = {main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>, boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&}; long unsigned int ...n = {0, 1}; Xn = {main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>, boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >}]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/basic_tuple.hpp:97:44:   required from ‘constexpr boost::hana::basic_tuple<Xs>::basic_tuple(Yn&& ...) [with Yn = {main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>, boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&}; Xn = {main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>, boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >}]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp:71:15:   required from ‘constexpr boost::hana::partial_t<std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, _Idx ...>, F, X ...>::partial_t(boost::hana::make_partial_t::secret, T&& ...) [with T = {main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>, boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&}; long unsigned int ...n = {0}; F = main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>; X = {boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >}]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp:61:74:   required from ‘constexpr boost::hana::partial_t<std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, __integer_pack()(sizeof ... (X ...))...>, typename boost::hana::detail::decay<Xs>::type, typename boost::hana::detail::decay<X, typename std::remove_reference<X>::type>::type ...> boost::hana::make_partial_t::operator()(F&&, X&& ...) const [with F = main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>; X = {boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&}; typename boost::hana::detail::decay<Xs>::type = main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>; typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type = main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/curry.hpp:149:24:   required from ‘constexpr decltype(auto) boost::hana::curry_t<n, F>::operator()(X&& ...) && [with X = {boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(auto:22)>, main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&}; long unsigned int n = 2; F = main()::<lambda(const auto:25&, const auto:26& ...)>]’
deleteme.cpp:31:37:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp:53:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >::overload_t()’
   53 |             , overload_t<G...>::type(static_cast<G_&&>(g)...)
      |                                                             ^
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp:51:28: note: candidate: ‘template<class F_, class ... G_> constexpr boost::hana::overload_t<F, G>::overload_t(F_&&, G_&& ...) [with F_ = F_; G_ = {G_ ...}; F = main()::<lambda(double)>; G = {main()::<lambda(const string&)>}]’
   51 |         constexpr explicit overload_t(F_&& f, G_&& ...g)
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp:51:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp:53:61: note:   candidate expects at least 1 argument, 0 provided
   53 |             , overload_t<G...>::type(static_cast<G_&&>(g)...)
      |                                                             ^
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp:42:12: note: candidate: ‘constexpr boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >::overload_t(const boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&)’
   42 |     struct overload_t
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp:42:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp:42:12: note: candidate: ‘constexpr boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >::overload_t(boost::hana::overload_t<main()::<lambda(double)>, main()::<lambda(const string&)> >&&)’
/usr/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp:42:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

However, if I define `visit` to be "manually" curried, it behaves as I expect ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GYdess6MW)):

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/curry.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

// the variant to visit
using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>;

int main() {
    std::vector<var_t> vec = {10, 15l, 1.5, "hello"};

    auto visitor = boost::hana::overload([](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
                    [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
                    [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; }
                    );

    auto visit_c = [](auto const& visitor_){
        return [&visitor_](auto const&... visited_){
            return std::visit(visitor_, visited_...);
        };
    };
    for (auto& v: vec) {
        visit_c(visitor)(v);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

---

(Example adapted from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).)

Comment: I'm not sure, and the documentation isn't clear on this, but I think the problem is that `partial` and `curry` don't work for variadic callables

Comment: @Caleth, [don't they?](https://godbolt.org/z/M3h6KE9bj)

Comment: I switched the `boost::hana::overload` out for a struct with `operator()` defined for each of the types and it seemed to compile. Not really an answer, but kind of interesting

Comment: It seems that the recursive inheritance is failing to detect the base case and trying to form `overload_t<>`, perhaps because its contained type is itself an `overload_t` specialization.

Comment: FWIW, making `visitor` const is sufficient to get it to compile: https://godbolt.org/z/Wf4jMq4Me

Comment: @DavisHerring, I have shortened the reproduction example. I think your comment is close to an answer...

Answer (score 0):

On top of the above MRE, I've verified that these assertions all pass,

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<L1, Ovl>);
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<boost::hana::overload_t<L2, L3>::type, Ovl>);
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<boost::hana::overload_t<L2, L3>, Ovl>);
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<L2, boost::hana::overload_t<L2, L3>::type>);
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<L3, boost::hana::overload_t<L2, L3>::type>);
```

which, given how [`boost::hana::ovearload_t`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/998033e9dba8c82e3c9496c274a3ad1acf4a2f36/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp#L42) is written, means that the instantiation of `boost::hana::overload_t<L1, L2, L3>` has this form (not valid C++, here I play the role of the compiler):

```cpp
struct overload_t<L1, L2, L3>
    : L1
    , overload_t<L2, L3>
{
    using type = overload_t;
    using L1::operator();
    using overload_t<L2, L3>::operator();

    template <typename F_, typename ...G_>
    constexpr explicit overload_t(F_&& f, G_&& ...g)
        : L1(static_cast<F_&&>(f))
        , overload_t<L2, L3>(static_cast<G_&&>(g)...) // error points here
    { }
};
```

Therefore, when the compiler sees `Ovl ovl2{ovl};`, it has to construct `ovl2` from `ovl`; to do so, there are two possibilities:

1. instantiating `template <typename F_, typename ...G_> constexpr explicit overload_t<L1, L2, L3>::overload_t(F_&& f, G_&& ...g)` with `F_ = overload_t<L1, L2, L3>&` and an empty pack `G_...`, which results in a constructor with signature `overload_t<L1, L2, L3>::overload_t(overload_t<L1, L2, L3>&)` which is good for copy a ***non-`const`** lvalue* (such as `ovl`);
2. using the copy constructor, the implicit definition of which is not prevented by the user-defined template constructor (see *Effective Modern C++* by Scott Meyers, page 115, Item 17).

The implicitly defined copy constructor, however, has signature `overload_t<L1, L2, L3>::overload_t(overload_t<L1, L2, L3> const&)`, which is not as good a match as `overload_t<L1, L2, L3>::overload_t(overload_t<L1, L2, L3>&)` when they are fed with the ***non-`const` lvalue*** `ovl`, so the compliler will have to choose the first alternative above, which will in turn make it try the construction `overload_t<L2, L3>()`, which maps nicely to the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to
‘boost::hana::overload_t<<lambda(double)>, <lambda(float)> >::overload_t()’
```

Making `ovl` `const` solves the problem because it makes the implicitly defined copy constructor, `overload_t<L1, L2, L3>::overload_t(overload_t<L1, L2, L3> const&)` an exact match; the template constructor too is an exact match when instantiated with `F_ = overload_t<L1, L2, L3> const&`, but the former is preferred because it is not templated.

`std::move`ing `ovl` too solves the problem, for the same reason: the implicitly defined copy constructor is an exact match for copying an rvalue, and it is preferred to the likewise exact match of the templated constructor.